# Cannot send "tags" via datadog in Amazon ECS, Fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, datadog, aws-fargate

I have configured datadog agent on Amazon ECS, Fargate. I can send all the intended metrics but I cannot send "tags".

I've set Environment variables in ECS task definitions.

```
DD_API_KEY  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DD_TAGS     env:stg
ECS_FARGATE true
```

I think most of the settings are all right because I can see the metrics which I want to see.
But tags, especially env:stg is missing in datadog UI and because of this weired error, some metrics is missing.

Does anyone know the reason of this error and the way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably too late, but it may be useful to others.
You can set tags by using the environment variables of the application container (not the agent container) by using DD_TAGS.